# tracking head rotation in c# with only using a camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im curious how you would find how you would find how much someones head rotated using only a camera in c#. I dont know where to start with this so thats why im bringing it up on here.

Comment: do you mean their *actual heads*, or the heads of a character?

Comment: this is using actual head.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, there would be no simple way of telling how much a head has rotated in unity only using a camera. The only method I could think of would be some OR (optical recognition). My best recommendation would be looking into the rigging of the character to be able to tell, as that has the direct rotational, scaling, and positional values in reference to the character.

Example: This characters bone #3 (which isn't the head, but doesn't directly matter) has been rotated 100 degrees along the X, and -90 degrees along the Z.
[image]